# Stunnel with NOCERT option

Tags: networking, network-programming, stunnel

I want to use stunnel without certificate.I found following

```
OCSPflag=NOCERT
```

I tried above but unable to start stunnel . Is there any other option to run stunnel without certificate.

If i would use stunnel without certificate would that be useful(it would secure communication)

Comment: What are you going to use stunnel for? Act as a server or as a client? As server I think you need a certificate.

Comment: I would be using as client which would connect with FIX server

Comment: I'm not sure if it would fix your problem, but there's a typo: it's NOCERTS (with an S)